# How can I display a set of data from 2 database tables? Winforms

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I created a Winforms app and a database with 2 tables in Visual Studio:

- `Member` - holds details like first name
- `Membership` - holds a membership type basic, VIP.

I want to display membership type from the `Membership` table and the `FirstName` from the `Member` table.

I have added the foreign key for the membership table to `Member`. Now I try to create the view as below. While this works, when I show results of the view , it creates all the requested data 3 times:

```
MemberID   FirstName   Type
-------------------------------
    1      Tommy       Basic
    2      Sammy       VIP
    3      Alley       Basic
    1      Tommy       Basic
    2      Sammy       VIP
    3      Alley       Basic
    1      Tommy       Basic
    2      Sammy       VIP
    3      Alley       Basic
```

The code for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Memberdetails]
AS 
    SELECT Member.MemberId, Member.FirstName, Membership.Type
    FROM [Member], [Membership]
```

Not sure how to fix it just to display it once.

Comment: Read up on `JOIN`, particularly `INNER JOIN`

Comment: can you share your key columns? TypeId in member table?  Please check membership table for multiple value against type.

Comment: You have to use INNER JOIN in your VIEW query.

Comment: @Flydog57 , Amazing thank-you so much . https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp.   found exactly what I need , and appreciate that you point me to what i should research rather than give me the answer. This is now resolved.

Comment: You don't really need a view, you can just use a `SELECT` statement

Comment: @jjstar when you solve your problem please post an answer of your own; it benefits you and future people that land on your question via Google

Comment: @CaiusJard , thanks for the comment. I cannot say I alone answered the question , that is i didn't solve it. other users here have, the above simply said join/inner join  that is as good as an answer as that simply all that was added to the code for it to work. see below also somebody had answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add field **MembershipId** to **Member** table.

You can use where clause

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Memberdetails]
AS 
   SELECT Member.MemberId, Member.FirstName, Membership.Type
   FROM [Member], [Membership]
   WHERE [MemberShip].[Id] = [Member].[MembershipId]
```

Or use join clause

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Memberdetails]
AS 
   SELECT Member.MemberId, Member.FirstName, Membership.Type
   FROM [Member]
   JOIN [Membership] ON [Membership].[Id] = [Member].[MembershipId]
```

Comment: *you can use where clause* - we have been able to avoid writing joins that way for 30 years; please don't recommend it; just go the JOIN route

Comment: hey thanks for the answer and comment. I did use the Join Clause , mostly because I had tried the WHERE clause several different ways and it never wanted to work. The join clause works perfectly first go.